# New LCD screen with random black screen

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, gnu-screen, monitors

I bought a new LCD screen and my computer's screen goes black for 1 second randomly while using Linux distributions. I was using dual boot having windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. Windows 8.1 worked without any error. My old LCD screen didn't have any kind of this problem on Ubuntu. I have tried another new LCD screen and it had the same issue. Right now, I have removed Ubuntu and trying to install Mint, but screen is also randomly flickering. Should I renew driver or something? I have tried changing refresh rate, it helped for sometime but had the same problem after that.

I have observed that while playing videos on Linux, the problem goes away. Why could this happen?

Result of lspci:

[image]

Comment: What video card, what monitor? Output of `lspci` ?

Comment: I am not able to post result of lspci as it is not too long, so I am attaching it to a post.